# Codeigniter Perpage Link Not Showing First In URL Pagination links

Tags: codeigniter

I am making my table head links sortable and orderable how ever my per_page does not show up first

`http://localhost/project-1/forum/category/1/&order=asc?per_page=1`

It should show like

`http://localhost/codeigniter/forum/category/1/?per_page=1&order=asc`

> Question when I click on the pagination links if the have been order or sorted how can I make sure that when I click on a pagination link even though has been order/sorted will still allways show ?per_page first in url.

```
$url = '';

if ($this->input->get('sort')) {
    $url .= '&sort=' . $this->input->get('sort');
}

if ($this->input->get('order')) {
    $url .= '&order=' . $this->input->get('order');
}

$config["base_url"] = base_url('forum/category') .'/'. $category_id .'/'.  $url;
```

Controller

```
<?php

class Forum extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('catalog/forum/forum_model');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }

    public function category() {
        $this->document->set_title('Forums');

        $category_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

        if ($this->input->get('sort')) {
            $sort = $this->input->get('sort');
        } else {
            $sort = 'message';
        }

        if ($this->input->get('order')) {
            $order = $this->input->get('order');
        } else {
            $order = 'asc';
        }

        $url = '';

        if ($this->input->get('per_page')) {
            $url .= '?per_page=' . $this->input->get('per_page');
        }

        if ($this->input->get('sort')) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->input->get('sort');
        }

        if ($this->input->get('order')) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->input->get('order');
        }

        $config["base_url"] = base_url('forum/category') .'/'. $category_id .'/'.  $url;
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->forum_model->total_category($category_id);
        $config["per_page"] = 1;
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
        $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $start = ($this->input->get('per_page')) ? $this->input->get('per_page') : '';

        $filter_data = array(
            'limit' => $config["per_page"],
            'start' => $start,
            'category_id' => $category_id,
            'sort' => $sort,
            'order' => $this->input->get('order')
        );

        $data['threads'] = array();

        $results = $this->forum_model->get_threads_for_forum($filter_data);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $data['threads'][] = array(
                'thread_id' => $result['thread_id'],
                'user_id' => $result['user_id'],
                'username' => $result['username'],
                'subject' => $result['subject'],
                'link' => site_url('thread') . '-' . $result['thread_id'],
                'total' => $this->forum_model->total_threads($result['thread_id']),
                'date_created' => date('d-m-Y', strtotime($result['date_created'])),
                'user_link' => site_url('user') . '-' . $result['user_id']
            );
        }

        $data['header'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/header/index');
        $data['footer'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/footer/index');
        $data['menu'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/menu/index');
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['back'] = site_url('forum');
        $data['thread'] = site_url('newthread') . '?fid=' . $category_id;

        $url = '';

        if ($order == 'asc') {
            $url .= '?order=desc';
        } else {
            $url .= '?order=asc';
        }

        $data['message'] = site_url('forum/category') .'/'. $category_id .'/'. $url;
        $data['sort'] = $sort;
        $data['order'] = '';

        $this->load->view('default/template/forum/forum_thread_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set your default category id if url does not contain:**

```
if ($this->uri->segment(3) == 'null') {
  $category_id = 1;  //set default for null
} else {
   $category_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
}
```

> Edit your config['base_url'] and add set $config['suffix'] if $_GET is not
>   empty.

**New Pagination config:**

```
$config["base_url"] = base_url('forum/category'); //no need custom category id
if (count($_GET) > 0) 
    $config['suffix']='?'.http_build_query($_GET,'',"&");//to encode requested data
$config["per_page"] = 1;
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
$config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
$config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
$config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
$config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
$config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
$config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
```

Comment: Now stops pagination from going back.

Comment: Thanks @wolfgang1983 , I have edited please check it now.

Comment: Don't understand where to put this `if (count($_GET) > 0) $config['suffix'] = '?' . http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");`

Comment: I have included whole $config check it now. It will work as you want. You can remove unnecessary code.

It will work like pagination with your $_GET params.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any:

```
$config[‘reuse_query_string’] = TRUE;
```

This will allow to use mixed type of urls. This was not possible before CI 3.0.